# C++ Dev: OS X Workstation, Build/Run/Debug on remote Linux machine?

Tags: linux, osx, c++, debugging

I'm an OS X "refugee" working on a Linux-specific C++ codebase (CMake based, if that matters.)

I've been trying to figure out a decent workflow that lets me edit source (preferably with rich editing support, like code-completion, etc) on OS X, but build, run and **debug** the source on a remote Linux machine. The link between the machines is fast and flexible -- I can share directories, or SSH/SFTP, or whatever -- so ideally that shouldn't be a big problem.

I've taken a look at NetBeans, which explicitly supports this workflow, but it's so clunky that it's not appreciably better than running Eclipse on the remote Linux machine via X windows (a crappy experience in its own right.) It looks like many of the JetBrains IDEs support things like this (PyCharm certainly does, and I'm a fan), but their nascent C++ offering, CLion, doesn't support remote development yet. (It's being tracked by [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-744))

Anyone have any recommendations? I'm mainly looking to keep OS X text input conventions (i.e. kb shortcuts) and native OS X style UI. Also willing to hack stuff up, within reason. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use almost IDE with remote debug facility on your project within a shared directory and either add the make step as:

- a remote run preparation step,
- as a macro on the local IDE or
- use a cross compiler tool chain to build on the Max then execute as a remote debug session.

I know from personal experience that the GCC tools include both cross compiler and remote debug clients, *(the GCC one even has facilities for downloading the built code before debugging it)*, and that many IDEs including Eclipse, [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), *(there is an OS-X build)* and many others include facilities for using these tools exactly this way as it is what we do things all the time in the embedded development world.